# PKCS11, OBJECT PIN

Tags: c, pkcs#11

I'm making pkcs11 module for web app. It's remote storage for certificates and it provides API for signing data. API for signing looks like this:
sign(int CertificateId, char* Password, void* data, int lenght)

In pkcs11 module, the whole storage is represented by one single token. In the C_Initialize section, I authenticate to the server. I find objects with another API call and everything is fine. The problem is, when I call C_SignInit or C_Sign function, I dont know how to get secondary password for my object. 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PKCS#11 all objects are protected with a User PIN. They don't have their own PINs. So there's no standard way to ask for a different PIN for the particular object.

Comment: So if I have n different private keys, I have to make n tokens?

Comment: @OndřejPřikryl No, you can have multiple keys on the token, but they need to be protected with one and the same PIN, passed in C_Login function.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of PKCS#11 is to have 1 password (PIN) to protect the whole token. Secondary authentication on keys located on the same token has been completly left out of the protocol. As stated in the 2.01 specification :

> Using a private key protected by secondary authentication uses the same process, and call sequence, as using a private key that is only protected by the login PIN. In fact, applications written for Cryptoki Version 2.01 will use secondary authentication without modification.

Which translates into: "secondary authentication is not our problem. Such mechanisms must be implemented OUTSIDE of our protocol".

However, they describe a trick to expose several PINs when the keys are actually located on the same token [here](http://interop.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v211/group__SEC__17__1__VIRTUAL__SLOTS__AND__TOKENS.html)

Link to 2.11 specification: [here](http://interop.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v211/)

Answer (score 1):

As Eugene Mayevski [writes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36445748/5128464) there is no such concept as "object PIN" in PKCS#11.

You may implement some variant of the following schema to get similar access control model:

Enrolling a key-pair:

1. Generate a key-pair via `C_GenerateKeyPair` and ensure the private key is generated as a session-only object (i.e. with `CKA_TOKEN==FALSE`). An alternative is to import the key pair somehow (not to be discussed here).
2. Generate a strong password (or use a user supplied one) and run it through some [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) to get "unlocking key". Keep this "unlocking key" in your application memory.
3. Generate a new persistent symmetric "derivation key" which allows key derivation only (i.e. `CKA_TOKEN==TRUE` and `CKA_DERIVE==TRUE`) using e.g. `CKM_AES_KEY_GEN`.
4. Derive a new "wrap key" session-only key object using e.g. `CKM_AES_CBC_ENCRYPT_DATA` with the "unblocking key" bytes as input diversification data and using the "derivation key" as a master key. The new key should be a session-only object and should allow only key wrapping (i.e. `CKA_TOKEN==FALSE` and `CKA_WRAP==TRUE`).
5. Wrap the private key object from step 1 using the "wrap key" into "key blob".
6. Store the "key blob" (inside token or outside of it).
7. Delete the private key from step 1 and the "wrap key". Nuke password and "unlocking key". (Do this step even if some of the previous steps fail)
8. The private key should not be accessible without knowing the password.

Using a key-pair:

1. Run the input password through the same KDF to get the "unlocking key".
2. Derive the "wrap key" in the same way as during the key enrollment but this time for unwrapping only (i.e. `CKA_TOKEN==FALSE` and `CKA_UNWRAP==TRUE`).
3. Unwrap the "key blob" into a new session-only private key object.
4. Delete the "wrap key". Nuke password and "unlocking key". (Do this step even if some of the previous steps fail)
5. Use the key-pair at your will.
6. Delete the private key. (Do this step even if some of the previous steps fail)

Wiping the key-pair:

1. Delete the associated "derivation key" and "key blob".

Some additional (random) notes:

- The used AES mechanisms are just examples. You would have to store the used IV together with "key blob" if using `CKM_AES_CBC_ENCRYPT_DATA`.
- Pay a lot of attention to all object attribute values (i.e. deny everything what is not needed). If your device supports some vendor defined extensions to control object usage then do use them (e.g. to enforce wrap/unwrap/derive mechanisms allowed).
- Remember to wipe/delete passwords and temporary keys from memory/session.
- Use vendor specific wrapping mechanisms as they probably provide better protection (if possible).
- A convenient way to delete session objects is to close the session.
- You may want to protect the integrity of the "key blob" if it is not provided by the wrapping mechanism.

Good luck!

Desclaimer: I am no crypto expert, so please do validate my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you call password that protect private keys in .pfx or .pvk files as   "secondary password" you are wrong. Those password is used to protect private keys in those files(.pfx or .pvk ) not the HSM one. There is no another password to protect keys in HSM. If you want to call api functions you have to login with user or admin PIN.

Comment: So if I have n different private keys, I have to make n tokens?

Comment: No, you can create different keys with different names. you can use keys with using object ID. you can find object ID  of keys with searching their names.

Comment: I dont think you get me right. I dont want to create keys, I want user to give me PIN and the only function where I can get PIN from user is C_Login, or am I wrong?